# How can IntelliJ find remote dependencies?

Tags: plugins, playframework, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I added the [Mailer plugin](https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/mailer) to my Play Framework 2 project.  It compiles and works fine, but IntelliJ can't resolve any of its classes.  I would normally just add the jar as a module in my IntelliJ project settings, but I don't have a jar.  As far as I understand, the plugin is automatically being pulled from some repository.  So how do I make IntelliJ aware of it?

I added this to conf/play.plugins

```
1500:com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin
```

And this as a dependency in project/build.scala

```
"com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.0.4"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to delete the reference to com.github.mpeltonen in my plugins.sbt file first.  Then as Bill said, I needed to run `play idea`.  If I tried to run `play idea` without deleting the reference I got this exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.sbtidea.SbtIdeaPlugin$.ideaSettings()Lscala/collection/Seq;
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolve problems like this with the [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) SBT plugin. Just add this to your `project/plugins.sbt` file:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.2.0")
```

Then, whenever you change your project dependencies, run `sbt idea` and your IntelliJ project will be updated.

Comment: How do I run that command?  I went to the project directory in terminal and tried to run it but I got "command not found".

Comment: You might not have sbt installed - you can also run `play idea` which should be equivalent.